# In XSLT, how do I truncate a string of numerals and add space before letters?

Tags: xml, string, xslt, truncate

I have such input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Article>
    <ProductNr>70001</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70001A</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70002I</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70002II</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70002.1</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70002.2</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70123</ProductNr>
    <ProductNr>70125A</ProductNr>
</Article>
```

I have Product Numbers and I want to transform it to Chapter Numbers. I snipped of an XML output below. What I need to to is to remove 70+ prefix and add space between number and letters. Do nothing with dots. Please help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Article>
    <ChapterNr>1</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>1 A</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>2 I</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>2 II</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>2.1</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>2.2</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>123</ChapterNr>
    <ChapterNr>125 A</ChapterNr>
</Article>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: No. As I know InDesign CC supports only W3C XSLT 1.0 recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather awkward to do in XSLT 1.0, with no regex support. Still, I believe you could boil it down to something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ProductNr">
    <ChapterNr>
        <xsl:variable name="num-start">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '70000')">6</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '7000')">5</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '700')">4</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '70')">3</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="num" select="substring(., $num-start)" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($num, '.')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="digits-only" select="translate($num, translate($num, '0123456789', ''), '')" />
                <xsl:variable name="count-digits" select="string-length($digits-only)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($num, 1, $count-digits)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length($num) > $count-digits">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($num, $count-digits + 1)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </ChapterNr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Please note the assumptions made here:**

1. The 70+ prefix has a known maximum length (`"70000"` in this
   example);
2. After the prefix there is a string of digits, followed by a string
   of alpha characters only (i.e. no digits will appear after the alpha
   characters).

If any of these assumptions is not true, you will have to use a recursive named template to determine the respective result.